# Sorting issues in flexigrid with "json" data

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I'm currently using flexigrid to display data in a current project, but am running into issues with its ability to properly sort certain columns that contain dates or numbers. The data is being sent from a ColdFusion CFC that selects the appropriate data and then delivers it in the proper "json" format. As the date/time stamps and other fields containing numbers are sent as "strings" they do not sort properly in the data grid.

Is this a limitation of Flexigrid or am I sending the data improperly to Flexigrid? I can provide examples of my code if that is helpful.

Comment: Well, I've looked at this issue some more and have determined that I was "barking up the wrong tree" so to say. The problem is that I'm using some MySql functions to format the data before I pass it to the grid and that is what seems to be breaking the sorting.

Comment: I'm using the DATEFORMAT function to format the dates and the regular FORMAT function to force all values to display with two decimal places. This seems to convert the value to a string and causes the sort to work accordingly. I thought about selecting the fields without the formatting for sorting purposes, but it appears that the query and the code I'm using to return the data as JSON want the query select columns and my datagrid columns to have a one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Flexigrid doesn't do any sorting at all as far as I remember. It just passes the sorting info to the server. So any issues with sorting data are server-side.

To sort client-side You would have to send all data records instead of n (n per page)

As for selecting and sorting - SQL does not forbid selecting a column twice in a query, so You can

```
SELECT sth, DATEFORMAT(my_date, sth) as when, my_date ORDER BY my_date;
```

After selecting data this way You just have to skip `my_date` when returning JSON for flexigrid.